# How to call google maps button events?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am designing an application for android, which uses google maps, and what i want is to hide the default buttons and design my own ones for the same functions, that is zooming in, zooming out and centering.

Here is my map object.

> private GoogleMap map;

Here is my on Click Method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnMapCenter:
                //TODO do the centering stuff
                break;
            case R.id.btnMapZoomIn:
                //TODO do the zooming in stuff
                break;
            case R.id.btnMapZoomOut:
                //TODO do the zooming out stuff
                break;
        }
    }
```

Please help me write the needed functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `animateCamera(CameraUpdate)` method ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate))).
[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#updating_the_camera_view)'s a useful guide.

Basic example:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
```